# Can a decentralized app know the true identity of its users?

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, decentralization, identity

I’ve been thinking about the architecture of decentralized applications.  I know certain applications like Uniswap and Augur don’t know the identity of its users. Would these applications still be decentralized if they know the identity of its users and is this a preferred style of dapps?

Answer (score 1):

Whether they know the identity or not, doesn't make them more or less decentralized. Then, on the other hand, you have to be a bit more specific about what you mean with "know the identity".

Many decentralized apps have limited functionality for only certain users. For example Uniswap liquidity can only be withdrawn if you have he required LP tokens. Or maybe some dapp limits functionality based on the user wallet address - only certain address can perform some functionality (probably based on previous executions).

So I'd say it depends on the level of "knowing" the user. If you mean stuff like KYC (Know Your Customer), then no decentralized app can do that kind of things, since that requires centralized processing by an off-chain entity.